# I m not getting different modal-title after pressing model button always same title i gets

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

My api data formate like this

```
{
id: "1",
video_url: "http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/videos/WomanSculptsClayMusic_042009083.mp4",
name: "Modeling Faces in Clay with Janet Blake",
description: "This workshop, lead by acclaimed sculptor, and OVCAA resident artist, Janet Blake, is a don't miss experience. Janet shares tips and tricks that have made her one of the foremost artists in modeling faces in clay. Her engaging style will have you clamoring for more.",
duration: "00:00:38",
created_by: "Ronald Winter, Video Producer, OVCAA ",
image: "http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/WomanSculptsClay_042009083.png",
thumbnail: "http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/WomanSculptsClay_042009083.png",
cropped: "http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/cropped/WomanSculptsClay_042009083.png",
file_name_original: "Woman sculpts clay_042009083.mp4",
popularity: "10",
category_id: "2",
category: "Craft",
keywords: "clay,face,janet blake,sculpture"
}
like this data i have
```

## My template file is

```
<div class="row-12" >
  <div class="row-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let list of activityList">
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">{{ list.name }}</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img [src]="list.image" width="320" height="240" />
            <div>Category: {{ list.category }}</div>
            <div>Duration: {{ list.duration }}</div>
            <div>Popularity: {{ list.popularity }}</div>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#myModal"
            >
              Watch Video
            </button>
            <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{list.name}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div >
          <video width="530" height="240" controls  [src] = "list.video_url">
             Your browser does not support the video tag.
         </video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In panel-heading we get different value using *ngFor. like Modeling Faces in Clay with Janet Blake,
Fire Dancers Shine Bright.
why i am getting video link after pressing watch now model button. all time i gets id=1 video url
please help me..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because you use the same id for all the modals: `id="myModal"`